# Creating multiple Object[][] arrays in bean or instantiating bean multiple times

Tags: java, arrays, spring, javabeans

I have multiple functions in model which returns Object[][] arrays . I need to use a bean but don't know which strategy to apply .All these arrays are returning different data. Should I do it a way like this?

```
public class VoiceMessagesBean 
{   
    Object[][] inbox_messages;
    Object[][] accepted_messages;
    Object[][] rejected_messages;
    Object[][] response_yes;
    Object[][] response_no;
    Object[][] feedback_messages;
    Object[][] processed_messages;
    Object[][] saved_messages;

    public Object[][] getInbox_Messages()
    {
        return inbox_messages;
    }

    public void setInbox_Messages(Object[][] inbox_messages)
    {
        this.inbox_messages=inbox_messages;
    }

    public Object[][] getAccepted_Messages()
    {
        return accepted_messages;
    }

    public void setAccepted_Messages(Object[][] accepted_messages)
    {
        this.accepted_messages=accepted_messages;
    }

    public Object[][] getRejected_Messages()
    {
        return rejected_messages;
    }

    public void setRejected_Messages(Object[][] rejected_messages)
    {
        this.rejected_messages=rejected_messages;
    }

    public Object[][] getResponse_Yes()
    {
        return response_yes;
    }

    public void setResponse_Yes(Object[][] response_yes)
    {
        this.response_yes=response_yes;
    }

    public Object[][] getResponse_No()
    {
        return response_no;
    }

    public void setResponse_No(Object[][] response_no)
    {
        this.response_no=response_no;
    }

    public Object[][] getFeedback_Messages()
    {
        return feedback_messages;
    }

    public void setFeedback_Messages(Object[][] feedback_messages)
    {
        this.feedback_messages=feedback_messages;
    }

    public Object[][] getProcessed_Messages()
    {
        return processed_messages;
    }

    public void setProcessed_Messages(Object[][] processed_messages)
    {
        this.processed_messages=processed_messages;
    }

    public Object[][] getSaved_Messages()
    {
        return saved_messages;
    }

    public void setSaved_Messages(Object[][] saved_messages)
    {
        this.saved_messages=saved_messages;
    }
}
```

Or should I make multiple instances of a bean in the controller and make a single Object Array in the bean as shown below and use a single object[][] array every time a function is called. But then I need to instantiate bean object multiple times.

```
public class MemberBean {
Object [][] memberObject;

public Object[][] getMemberObject() {
    return memberObject;
}
```

What is better method of doing?

Comment: Better is to use no arrays!

Comment: Without further or deeper explanation about the requirements, it is impossible to have a preference here. In fact, I never would have `Object[][]` in my API.

Comment: @OlegS. my fucntions return Object arrays so for that i need to use bean for storage ?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose my functions in the model returns Object[][] arrays and they are many. So for that the first code block does the purpose of saving those functions in arrays in bean

Comment: @Teena No, it is better to not use arrays at all :)

Comment: @OlegS. how will den i solve my purpose for the queries which returns data as 2-d array n i am using mvc so i need to return it to the controller

Comment: Arrays are a data structure with which you can implement a specific requirement. This should only be known internally in a class. First, I would rarely have arrays as parameters or return types of my public methods. Second, I never would have a 2D Object array in that public API.

Comment: Create a meaningfull class that holds just the data you want. Your queries then return instances of this class, and your controller consumes these instances. From then on, you can simply change the internal implementation of that class (by maybe getting rid of arrays or having more complex data structure or whatever). A first step to refactor your code.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thanks I got it now :)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose One more query now is What should i use to return my query result instead of an array from model to controller as now m not willing to use Object[][] ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Better you should use instances of a class bcoz main motive of a class is reduce occurrence of a variable and better use its instance.